# Base64 decode possible payload?

Tags: exploit

I was innocently looking at the source code of a page, minding my own business when I stumbled upon this: (this is only part since it exceeds the 30,000 character limit)

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYW...
```

Is this a payload? That's a lot of text cranked into a image. I decoded it to what looked like hex. Can this be decoded to reveal a message?

Comment: Not everything which looks strange has something to do with information security. What you see is a perfectly normal and innocent and standardized [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

Answer (score 3):

While anything might be malicious, I see no reason to think it is anything other than what it claims to be: [an inline image encoded with base64](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/). This is part of the HTML spec and is done for a number of reasons, typically having to do with performance (although I'm dubious about the wisdom of using this technique on larger files).

Most likely your browser already decoded it to reveal a message in the form of a JPEG image. If you find this tag on the actual page I'm sure you will find your browser is displaying an image.

Comment: Decoding the base 64 snippet in the question reveals the expected magic codes for a JPEG/JFIF file. You (Jayson) could decode the entire string into a file, and try your favorite image viewer on it.

Comment: Thanks guys. The reason I had suspicions is because the link was a weird http link and I thought maybe someone did some MSFVenom payload into the image on the website. I appreciate the answers.